# Android.text.format.Time not setting isDst correctly?

Tags: java, android, dst

I'm trying to set a Time object to be 15 minutes past the current time, according to following:

```
    Time time = new Time("EST");
    time.setToNow();
    time.minute += 15;
    time.normalize(true);
```

However, after time.setToNow(), I notice in the debugger that the time object's isDST field equals 0, which indicates not in DST according to the [reference.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html) Also according to the reference, time.normalize(true) method is supposed to set the isDst field to -1, then compute the correct value for isDst, but in my case the isDst value stays the same, at 0, so the time is shifted back one hour.

I know we're in DST now, so I expect the isDst field to reflect this, but it's not. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know we're in DST now, so I expect the isDst field to reflect this, but it's not. Any ideas?

It's possible that it's because you've given `"EST"` as a time zone. That's Eastern *standard* time - which has no concept of DST.

If you use something like `"America/New_York"` instead, I suspect you'll get a different answer. That's a zoneinfo time zone identifier, which covers both EST and EDT at different points in the year.